# Hive query is not working

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to use regexp_extract on hive.

I have data which is varying in nature, such as:

```
a2=new something
a1=asdasdsad;a2=old something;a3=asadasdsadsa
a2=Some place;alksndklsand;a1=asdklsad
```

Now, I need to extract the a2 data only. The semi colon denotes the end of a2 data but it might not present in every case.

What I've been trying is to concat a ';' to the column and then running `regexp_extract` to extract the data between the "a2=" and the first ";" (addding the ";" in order to make the logic compatible with all the cases).

This is my query (I have verified that the regexp works):

```
select regexp_extract(concat(column_name,;),'.*a2=?(.*?);',1) from table;
```

But I get an error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:43 cannot recognize input near '.' '*' 'a2' in select expression
```

I'm at my wit's end with this, any help would be appreciated.

I'm using hive version 0.13.1

Comment: @vks I'm sorry, could you elaborate?

Comment: You already asked this question and it is same.There is no change

Comment: The previous question was regarding the regexp, this question is regarding the hive failure.
I fail to see how they are the same.

Comment: I am not asking for a regexp here.

Comment: You asked for regex over there which works in hive.Now you have the regex which does not work on hive?

Comment: I'm sorry, Let me clarify. I verified that the regexp works on www.regex101.com.
I have not been able to run the hive query on hive at all.
It throws me an error.
Hence, this question.
Thanks.

Comment: I've never used regexp_extract before and the documentation for it online is very limited. Further, I couldnt find a single example where regexp_extract has been used to extract data from a column.